# Inner div not getting center

Tags: html, css

I am centering inner div `insTabsContainer` using `margin: 0 auto` but it's not getting center. Will you guys tell me what's I did wrong here.

HTML

```css
.insTabsContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.insTabs {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #E5E7E9;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2C3E50;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="insTabsContainer">
    <div class="insTabs active">Text</div>
    <div class="insTabs">Text</div>
    <div class="insTabs">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as posted this works for me here

Comment: @ManishPatel Just updated my code, mistakenly typed that here. But this thing is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flex. for this.

```css
.insTabsContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.insTabs {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #E5E7E9;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2C3E50;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.insTabs:last-child {
 margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="insTabsContainer">
    <div class="insTabs active">Text</div>
    <div class="insTabs">Text</div>
    <div class="insTabs">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
margin: 0  auto;
```

it should have a width, but you can use simply

> display:table;

```
.insTabsContainer {
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set width in order to see that it's center:

```
.insTabsContainer {margin: 0 auto; width: 90%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `flex-box`

```css
.insTabsContainer {
  
}
.insTabsContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.insTabs {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #E5E7E9;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2C3E50;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
  <div class="insTabsContainer  d-flex">
    <div class="insTabs active">Text</div>
    <div class="insTabs">Text</div>
    <div class="insTabs">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```